# SQL query for selecting records in a hierarchy

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query, to select records with the max number value [if duplicate exists for a order+key combination], based on the following hierarchy:

1. If Order+Key Combination has duplicates, and one of them has'30' code- We will select this record(having 30 code).
2. If Order+Key Combination does not have '30' code and there are duplicates- We will select the record having max number.
3. If Order+Key Combination does not have any duplicates- We will select that record as it is.

This is a sample input and output:

[image: here]

In my example,13+1 (order+key combination) has 2 records, so we will pick up max of them.
14+1 also has 2 records, so we will pick up max of them.
15+1 has 2 records, but for one of them the code is 30- hence we will pick up that record, and will not consider max criteria for this order+key.
16+1 has only 1 record, so we pick up that 1 record.

Please let me know on how can we solve this query. I am unable to think how shall I proceed.

Comment: What if a record has no "code = 30", and there are two different code having the same max number, how would you choose ? For example, a record with (13, 1, 14, 225) is added to your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  a.order, 
  a.key, 
  case when b.code is NOT NULL then b.code ELSE a.code end as code, 
  case when b.number is NOT NULL then b.number ELSE max(a.number) end as number 
from 
  abc a 
  left join abc b on a.code = b.code 
  and b.code = 30 
GROUP by 
  a.order + a.key
```

Comment: This only works if you have a single record with code = 30.

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses 2 subqueries, first one finds records with max(number), second finds records with code = 30 and the largest number.

It will work correctly with multiple "code = 30" records and duplicate rows.

```
   select maxes.`order`, maxes.`key`, coalesce(thirties.`code`, maxes.`code`) as `code`, coalesce(thirties.`number`, maxes.`number`) as `number` 
    from
        (select distinct a.`order`, a.`key`, a.`code`, a.`number` from
            input a left join input b on a.`order` = b.`order` and a.`key` = b.`key` and a.number < b.number where b.order is null) as maxes
        left join
        (select `order`, `key`, `code`, max(number) as `number` from input where `code` = 30 group by `order`, `key`, `code`) as thirties
        on maxes.order = thirties.order and maxes.key = thirties.key
    order by maxes.`order`, maxes.`key
```

*Update:*
Here is a different solution that would keep all the "30" records and additionally return records with max numbers that have no "30" code.

```
select distinct a.`order`, a.`key`, a.`code`, a.`number` 
from
 input a left join input b on a.`order` = b.`order` and a.`key` = b.`key` and a.number < b.number 
 left join (select distinct `order`, `key` from input where code = 30) as x on a.`order` = x.`order` and a.`key` = x.`key`
where x.`order` is null and b.`order` is null
union all
select `order`, `key`, `code`, `number` from input where `code` = 30
```

Comment: I have a question. Whenever we have a 30 for a order+key, we pick up that record straight without even checking if its a max or not. Its like a priority. Basically none of the records with 30's should get eliminated. We select max for order+key only when it's not a 30. So how does the second query works in your post?

Comment: If for a order+key we have all 30's then we should be picking up all of them.

Comment: The query I posted would get one "30" record with the largest 'number'. If you want to get all "30" records you would have to rearrange the subqueries.

Comment: Take a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my solution. Let me know if this works for you.

Solution 1:

(See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=8d016819cbefb781557771e8902e3e3b))

(a) Subquery 1 (Line 12 to 14)  : **t1**

- Check and see if each unique (order + key) has at least one record having code = 30.
- 'Y' - Yes for having one or more and 'N' for none.
- Result: This gives 4 records, 4 unique (order + key) with a 'Y' or 'N'

(b) Subquery 2 (Line 4 to 16) : **t2**

- This subquery uses your sample table "input" and left join with subquery 1 (**t1**)
- For each unique (order + key), get the maximum number based on conditions as follows:

  - If the unique (order + key) has code = 30 somewhere, and this record has a code = 30, then get the maximum of the number
    *(Note: this may seem confusing to you, try running the subquery t2)*
  - If the unique (order + key) has no code = 30, then get maximum of the number
- Result: This gives 4 records, 4 unique (order + key) with their maximum number (with conditions)

(c) Final part (Line 1 to 18) :

- The most outer part of query uses your sample table "input" and inner join with subquery 2(**t2**)
- Since subquery 2 (**t2**) results give you "order, key and number", you join with "input" to get the "code" column

```
SELECT i.`order`, i.`key`, i.code, i.number
FROM input i
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        i.`order`, i.`key`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN i.code = 30 AND t1.has_code_30 = 'Y' THEN i.number
                 WHEN t1.has_code_30 = 'N' THEN i.number
            END
        ) AS max_number 
    FROM input i
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT `order`, `key`, MAX(CASE WHEN code = 30 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS has_code_30
        FROM input
        GROUP BY `order`, `key`
    ) t1 ON i.`order` = t1.`order` AND i.`key` = t1.`key`
    GROUP BY i.`order`, i.`key`
) t2 ON i.`order` = t2.`order` AND i.`key` = t2.`key` AND i.number = t2.max_number
ORDER BY i.`order`, i.`key`;
```

Solution 2:

In cases where you have same (order + key) with two different code having the same max_number. See table below:

| order | key | code | number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 1 | 13 | 225 |
| 13 | 1 | 14 | 225 |

`MAX()` is used here assuming that you select the maximum code, else you can change to `MIN()`.

If you wish to retain both records, simply use "Solution 1".

```
SELECT i.`order`, i.`key`, MAX(i.code), i.number
FROM input i
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        i.`order`, i.`key`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN i.code = 30 AND t1.has_code_30 = 'Y' THEN i.number
                 WHEN t1.has_code_30 = 'N' THEN i.number
            END
        ) AS max_number 
    FROM input i
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT `order`, `key`, MAX(CASE WHEN code = 30 THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS has_code_30
        FROM input
        GROUP BY `order`, `key`
    ) t1 ON i.`order` = t1.`order` AND i.`key` = t1.`key`
    GROUP BY i.`order`, i.`key`
) t2 ON i.`order` = t2.`order` AND i.`key` = t2.`key` AND i.number = t2.max_number
GROUP BY i.`order`, i.`key`, i.number
ORDER BY i.`order`, i.`key`;
```